# ColdFusion syntax highlighting for e-texteditor

Tags: coldfusion, e-texteditor

Does anyone know of a way to add ColdFusion syntax highlighting to e-texteditor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the cf-textmate bundle here http://cftextmate.andyjarrett.co.uk/.  Pretty much anything that will work with Textmate will work with E.  Color schemes, bundles, shortcuts.

Comment: Not sure how familiar you are with E or TextMate but I did a short screencast a few months back on using E with ColdFusion http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2011/09/screencast-using-e-texteditor-to-write.html

Comment: The link is no longer active